# Alfresco 5.1.x community edition created process using activiti

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am new to alfresco i have created process`alfresco activiti` using eclipse in the process i used service task task option in properties task type provide 3 types `1 .java class`, `2.expression,` `3.java delegates`
which one is better to use call external application from workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the different between JavaDelegate and Expression

**JavaDelegate** are instantiated by Spring.This means a workflow can call custom classes that have full access to Alfresco Spring beans. It allows your workflow to make delegate calls that can manipulate content it can also add or remove content from the workflow package itself.You can also add your other complex buisness logic there. So, if you have complex implementation to do during process you should go for this.

**Expressions:** For doing small operations like updating status of document or updating one or two properties of content within workflow you need to consider this. Because in expression you can use alfresco javascript to achieve all those things.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks lot ,can you refer some example